# Fail compilation if a specific method is being used in code. Is there any way of doing that?

Tags: android, lint

In my project we need to make sure ALL timestamps throughout the code are generated using `System.currentTimeMillis()`. Another way to generate a time stamp is by using Android's LocationManager Location object. It has a `location.getTime()` method. 
So for instance, is there any way to make sure that if  `location.getTime()` was used any where in the code, compilation will fail with an error.
I was thinking about using LINT but not sure if it is capable of such a thing. Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Thanks, updated title to indicate the method is used in code and not called during run time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Lint is capable of doing this. Although you'll need to set up the project initially. You could have a look at [Timber how they are detecting calls to Log.d](https://github.com/JakeWharton/timber/blob/b566f41af65de253aee54ff0da16092ffe972ab7/timber-lint/src/main/java/timber/lint/WrongTimberUsageDetector.java#L78) and then adjust this to your needs.